# Can't import Dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to run this code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Dataframe(["asdfasdf"])
```

Also I have tried with:

```py
df = pd.Dataframe(data=["asdfasdf"])
```

I have tried with python version 3.8.10 and 3.9.5. Also with pandas 0.25 and 1.2. I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/aitor/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 244, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can try `pd.dataFrame` and then `pd.DataFrame`, one of them should work I think.

Comment: You have invalid attribute name. Its ```pd.DataFrame``` with capital D and F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame()`
If you are unsure about something like that normally your IDE should do suggestions for auto-completion.

Like if you enter: `pd.Da` ...

[image]

Also you can always check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).